# Angular TypeScript error - Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'any[]'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an issue with types in my Angular component. I have a form that gets a value from input and sends data to server. I want the data to have type `specs: string[]` but the compiler throws me an error:

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'any[]'

Howewer if I change it to `specs = []` it works well. I searched Angular and TypeScript docs for explaining but didn't find any answer for my issue.

Here is my HTML component:

```
<div class="container list-group" [formGroup]="specForm" (ngSubmit)="setSpec()">
  <div class="list-group-item information">
    Speciality: <a href="#" class="header-picture"><img src="assets/static/img/edit.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group-item info-field-list">
    <div class="info-field-name">
      <p>Sector:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info-field-value" *ngFor="let user of users;let i=index">
      <div class="info-field-value">
        <a class="url"> {{user.speciality}} </a> (3lvl)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-field-value">
      <input type="text" class="spec-input" formControlName="speciality" placeholder="Write text"><span
        class="icon icon-plus" (click)="setSpec()"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And TS file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { AuthenticationService } from '@services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-speciality',
  templateUrl: './speciality.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./speciality.component.css']
})
export class SpecialityComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() user;
  specs: string[];
  specForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  loading = false;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.specForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      speciality: ['']
    });
    this.authService.getUser().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        //this.specs = data.speciality;
      });
  }

  get s() { return this.specForm.controls; }

  setSpec() {
    // activating submission flag for patch function
    console.log(this.specs)
    let newSpec = this.specs.push(this.s.speciality.value)
    this.submitted = true;
    console.log(this.specs)

    if (!this.specForm.valid) {
      return
    }

    this.authService
      // sending values to auth service function
      .specAdd(newSpec)
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.submitted = false;
        },
        error => {
          this.loading = false;
        });
  }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is ```data.speciality```?

Comment: It's data from server but it's not relevant now. The problem is in specs type, data is OK

Comment: It's relevant it seems data.speciality is number that you are assigning to string array.

Comment: But it throws an error although I've commented that line

Comment: So in which line are you getting error?

Comment: ERROR in src/app/modules/core/components/speciality/speciality.component.ts:34:5 - error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
`this.specs = this.specs.push(this.s.speciality.value)`

Comment: It seems that Angular is detecting input value as number although it's always a string and I'm confused

Comment: It's obvious, you are assigning push result in your array. just  write ```this.specs.push(this.s.speciality.value)```

Comment: array.push returns a number that shows array length not array itself.

Comment: It should be ```this.specs.push(this.s.speciality.value)``` then ```let newSpec = this.specs```

Comment: Thank you but now th error is `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` for this line `this.specs.push(this.s.speciality.value)` but I have initialised specs, how could it be undefined?

Comment: You just declared it not initialize, try ```specs: string[] = [];```

Comment: Oh, yes, it helped. Thanks a lot and sorry for bothering, such silly errors...

Comment: You're welcome, will post it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning Array.push result to array, Array.push returns a number that shows the array length, just in first push to array then assign the array to new one:

```
let newSpec = this.specs.push(this.s.speciality.value)
```

should be:

```
this.specs.push(this.s.speciality.value)
let newSpec = this.specs
```